# Sum of times in divs how to show days?

Tags: jquery

I have a load of dynamically generated divs that contain a time string, for example 0:03:15. These are song duration times.
I have a script that adds these times together and displays the sum of the times, but I can only get hours, minutes and seconds to work. I'm trying to get days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Here's my code with some of the newbie stuff I have tried:

```
function getSeconds(time) {
  var parts = time.split(":");
 return parseInt(parts[0], 12) * 86400 + parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(parts[2], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[3], 10);

// return parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[2], 10);
}

//select all the elements
var totalSeconds = $(".durationhold")
    .map( function(ind, elem) { //convert the jQuery object into the array  
        var text = $(elem).text();  //get the text from the anchor
        return getSeconds(text);    //set the index to the total seconds
    })
    .get()  //gets the array out of the jQuery object
    .reduce( function(runningTotal, currentValue){  //Now to combine all the values into one
        return runningTotal + currentValue;  //sum up the values
    },0);  //The initial starting value

//Now get the hour, minutes, and seconds from the total seconds
var days = parseInt (totalSeconds / 86400 );
var hours = parseInt( totalSeconds / 3600 );
var minutes = parseInt( totalSeconds / 60 ) % 60;
var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

//left pad numbers less than ten
if(hours<10) hours = "0" + hours;
if(minutes<10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if(seconds<10) seconds = "0" + seconds;


$("#out").html("Total Time: " + (days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds));
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tlm2408/aLrrxd3y/2/) with some made up times for demonstration.
Is there a faster way to do the same thing. The can be from one up to 5000 or more results.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want he quick answer, change

`var hours = parseInt( totalSeconds / 3600 );`

to

`var hours = parseInt( totalSeconds / 3600 ) % 24;`

For exactly the same reason as you do `% 60` on your minutes, you are only interested in the hours that remain after you display the full days.

---

Allow me to suggest a different approach however. I'll probably get some comments for "using a library for such a trivial task", but irl it is probably what I would do. For anything that has to do with times or dates in js, I always use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), a toolbox just for that. It has a an object called `duration` that perfectly fits your needs.

All the javascript in your fiddle can be replaced with this piece of code ( assuming you include moment.js first):

```
// caculate total duration
var duration = moment.duration(0);
$(".durationhold").each(function() {
    duration.add($(this).text());
});

// output
var days = Math.floor(duration.asDays());
days = days + (days == 1 ? ' day ' : ' days ');
var time = moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('H:mm:ss'); // convert to date to (ab)use it's formatting
$("#out").html("Total Time: " + days + time);
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLrrxd3y/3/)

Unfortunately the `duration` has no `format` method, so I had to get creative to get the output right, but other then that I think the code speaks for itself. Feel free to ask though if anything is unclear!

Comment: Thank you Pevara, The library works better, unfortunatly once I get above about 1000 results it is quite slow about 10-15 seconds to display results. I think there might be too much data to display quickly. The first method breaks after about 600 songs and returns NaN for each number.

Comment: I would probably look in to printing the actual (milli)seconds value as an attribute on your html. That way you can just sum these, and initiate the duration with that value. That way you skip a lot of parsing, so that should perform considerably better.

Comment: I ended up using your code with moments.js, moved some other scripts around and got it down to about 1 second for 3000 songs... Woo Hoo. Thank you very much.

Comment: I had a go at optimising the calcs for performance and ended up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v7cvm0aL/1/). For 1000 iterations (6000 summations) I'm getting duration as low as 32 ms. That's in Chrome on a 2.6GHz dual core Pentuim desktop. It's not worth another answer but maybe the code is worth raiding for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
days = 0;
if(hours > 24){
  days = Math.floor(hours/24);
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thank you llian, but where do I put that? Sorry as stated I'm a newbie.

Comment: After the 3 ifs 
if(hours<10) hours = "0" + hours;
if(minutes<10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if(seconds<10) seconds = "0" + seconds;